# Install Laravel gives Apache Default Home Page

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, laravel, nginx

I bought a server with Digital Ocean and have been trying to setup Laravel for 2 days now. The main tutorial [How to install laravel with an nginx web server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) and the result gives me a `Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page`. When I go to the IP address, it gives me a `Welcome to NGINX` page. I need to get this server up and running in the next few hours for a Pitch my partner and I are doing but it is not working.

Anyone know of a fix?

Also, NGINX will not restart. It says `* Restarting nginx nginx [fail]` and when I do `nginx -t` it says:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

and it gives the same result when I say `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: Check out nginx error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove apache2 from your server and start nginx as @Sw0ut said then start nginx by typing service nginx start open your nginx.conf file located at

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

and make suitable changes, possibly working conf would be

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

root   /location/to/your/www/public/folder;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log  warn;

location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

#redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}


location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass            unix:/location/to/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index           index.php;
    include                 fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    root           html;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}
}
```

unix:/location/to/php5-fpm.sock; the location of php5-fpm in most cases will be /var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

also chmod 755 /app/storage folder if that doesn't works try 777

and restart nginx if that doesn't works stop nginx and start it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you uninstall all apache2 stuff before trying to run nginx.

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2 apache2-utils
sudo service nginx start
```